# using regular expressions to pull information from a file

Tags: regex, grep

```
grep -H "httpd" /Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top
```

I am greping a file and looking for httpd consuming more than 0.00% of CPU.  So the output looks like this

```
/Users/sars/logs/2012-04-03-021/server1/top:10182 root            15  96    0 50352K 12880K ucond   2  48:01  0.00% httpd
```

I want to only see the output for results that are something other than 0.00% on this output line

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` again:

```
grep -H "httpd" /Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top | grep -vw 0.00%
```

Comment: that worked well.  is there a way to not have that filter 100.00% ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at awk instead of grep alone.  You get a lot more flexibility and don't have to deal with so many pipes.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    minimum=10; # only show lines greater than this percent
  }

  # skip lines that are not httpd
  $12 != "httpd" { next; }

  # remove the "%" from the cpu usage column
  { sub(/%/, "", $11) }

  # print lines whose % is higher than minimum
  $11 > minimum { print; }
' /Users/sars/logs/testlogs/2012-04-02*/*/top
```

Some adjustments may be required; I haven't seen your data, so I haven't actually tested this.

If I were doing this for myself, I'd either store the awk script as a stand-alone tool to be called from within a shell script, or I'd embed it in the shell script in a function.  Can't really recommend without knowing how you plan to use this.